# Linear programming: Condition on index variable

Tags: linear-programming

Let $i \in \{1,2,...n\}$. And let $X_i \in \{0,1\}$.

I need to write the condition: if all $X_i$ where $i$ is even index take the value 1, then there need to be at least three $X_i$ with value $0$ for all $i$'s with odd index.

The problem I am having is that I cannot put this into one equation if the condition does not hold.

It is obviously that is will not work if I type this: $\sum_{i = even}X_i \geq \sum_{i = odd}X_i + 3$, because if the upper condition does not hold, that the above equation need not to be fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the condition on even terms as a boolean should work, like this:

$$\left(\prod_{i\: even}X_i\right)\left(\sum X_i\right)\le n-3$$

Comment: What about $\sum X_i \leq n -3(\prod_{i \: even} X_i)$

Comment: That works too, I guess. I'm not saying mine is the only way.